# Academic Study of Islamic leadership should be allowed

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, politics

There are already many academic journals which study political nature of Islam which includes Islamic laws dealing with Islamic government. Islamic leadership laws should not be clubbed with the usual "politics" tag. We as muslim can not deny that Islam is a complete deen which also governs the political handlings of the Muslim world. It defines in detail the government mandated by Islam. Infact there are many narrations to suggest that there is no Islam without Jamah(Group\state) and its leaderships, hence I would suggest that academic study of Islamic leaderships be allowed. Currently two questions or more questions were deleted which just asked questions like :

"Is ISIS a valid Islamic caliphate according to the rules of Islam"?

"What are the conditions to establish a caliphate?"

Also  similar questions on political history of Islam were deleted almost on sight by a single mod after putting them on hold. Hence I would suggest that such seemingly political questions should be handled in an academic pursuit.